# Custom Form Results in 404 Page

Tags: magento2, forms

I'm trying ti implement a search form, and a bit confused on how to build the results page.

I built my `/etc/routes.xml` file (updated id and frontName)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="fitment_results" frontName="fitment_results">
            <module name="EkkoMedia_FitmentSearch"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And my `/Controller/Index.php` file

```
<?php

namespace EkkoMedia\FitmentSearch\Controller;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Result extends Action
{
    /** @var PageFactory $resultPageFactory */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Result constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * The controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $year = $this->getRequest()->getParam('year');

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        /** @var Messages $messageBlock */
        $messageBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages',
            'answer'
        );
        if (isset($year)) {
            $messageBlock->addSuccess('Year: ' . $year);
        }else{
            $messageBlock->addError('You didn\'t enter a year!');
        }

        $resultPage->getLayout()->setChild(
            'content',
            $messageBlock->getNameInLayout(),
            'answer_alias'
        );

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

And my `/view/frontend/layout/fitment_results_index.xml` file (updated file name)

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
</page>
```

But when I submit my form (`action="fitment_results"`), I get a 404 error

**UPDATE (Added phtml)**

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="productSearch" action="fitment_results" method="get">
        <select name="year" id="select_year" class="ui-selectmenu-button" tabindex="1">
            <option>Year</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
        </select>

        <select name="make" id="select_make" tabindex="2">
            <option value="">Make</option>
            <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
        </select>

        <select name="model" id="select_model" tabindex="3">
            <option value="">Model</option>
            <option value="F-150">F150</option>
        </select>

        <select name="trim" id="select_trim" tabindex="4">
            <option value="">Model</option>
            <option value="FX4">FX4</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" id="search_submit" value="Find Products">
     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see, the `routeId` can not contain the '-' character. You should change the `routeId` and `routeName` to `fitment_results`. Hope it help!

Comment: Made the change to both my routes.xml and my form action, but still getting a 404

Comment: For clarification, is the `routeName` the URL?

Comment: `routeName` is your base url of your module

Comment: Try to remove `var/generation` folder and clean cache

Comment: In that case, what if my module is a block being displayed in the header of every page, rather than its own page?

Comment: you have to also change the layout file `fitment-results_index.xml`

Comment: It's just your url for front end controller.

Comment: When you say change `fitment-results_index.xml` do you mean the filename or a line inside the file?

Comment: The file name mate, the layout will load when you call the same controller. For ex: When you call `filment-result/index`, the layout with the name `fitment-results_index.xml` will be load.

Comment: I updated that and still getting a 404. See question edit for changes made

Comment: your action might be `fitment_results/index`, Let me see the phtml code where you insert the action.

Comment: Added test.phtml

Comment: Try to replace: `$block->getUrl('fitment_results/index')` inside you action tag in your template

Comment: Replace method to POST. In your controller, you can get the value by `$this->getRequest()->getPostValue()`

Comment: Still directs me to my home page

Comment: what are the queries?

Comment: Now that its `POST` they aren't showing, with `GET` its `http://example.com/?year=2004&make=Ford&model=F-150&trim=FX4`

Comment: Yes, now  It work. You can search in you controller or you block